# '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: c++, command-line

I just started learning C++, and I've been trying to run my program from the command line using:

```
g++ helloworld.cpp
```

which works, then I typed

```
./a.out
```

then it returns the error '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command. 
I tried doing `a.out`, but it returns:

> 'a.out' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I'm pretty new to the command line so it might be quite a novice problem. I'm using the gnu gcc compiler. My code is just a simple code for printing "helloworld", and it doesn't seem to be a problem with the code since the line `g++ helloworld.cpp` doesn't throw up any error. Just to add, I'm using windows 8.

Comment: Is the file a.out present in your directory?

Comment: Try doing `g++ helloworld.cpp -o a.exe`
Then run `./a.exe`

Comment: Are you sure there's no space after the dot?

Comment: What kind of command line are you using?  What platform, what shell?

Comment: Sounds like you are running on windows...(you don't need to do any tricks like `./` to run an application in the current directory).

Comment: bash on Linux will recognize `. ./a.out` where the first dot is an internal command meaning run the next thing, and the next dot means the current directory, and the a.out is the file in the current directory.  crashmstr might be on to something there, with Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess would be that a.out is not in your directory. Usually, when compiling your program from the command line, add the `-o` flag and name your executable (like `helloworld.exe`). Then you'll be sure that an executable of that name is actually being created.

In your case, since you're most likely running Windows, without specifying a `-o` flag, the default is **a.exe** and not **a.out**, so when you used `./a.out` that executable didn't exist.  In this case, you can run your program by typing `a` or `a.exe`.  You don't need the leading `./` on Windows.

Comment: Exactly why she should be specifying a name for her executable and a suffix no? If she wants to run a.out, she uses `-o a.out` and if she wants a.exe she does `-o a.exe`

Comment: Ah, i see what you meant now. I guess my "answer" is more of a rule of thumb so she can avoid problems in the future. I'll edit.

Comment: ahh thank you! i realised a.out indeed isn't in my directory. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

```
./a.out
```

If you are in *NIX world, using linux or any other UNIX related platforms
.(dot) means current directory and a.out is an executable.

```
ls -l a.out
```

list its permissions and make sure it has executable permission. If it dont have use following command to give it permission; usually it should have when your generated the a.out file.

```
chmod 755 a.out
```

If your file is not in current directory use the absolute path to invoke the executable file

```
<absolute_path>/a.out
```

It should work if you have taken care all above criteria.

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows world, "\" is used to separate files and directories:

```
C:\Windows\System32\Etc
```

However most other operating systems, and the web, use "/"

```
file:///c/windows/system32/etc
/etc/motd
```

In Unix "." refers to the current directory, and Windows/DOS mostly support this.

The Unix-based compilers expect you to specify an output file name for a compilation, and the default is "a.out". But you can override it with "-o"

```
g++ test.cpp -o test.exe
```

This creates a file called "test.exe" in the current directory. If you are using MinGW's "bash" command line, you should be able to run the above executable by typing:

```
./test.exe   # note: no spaces!
```

at a "$" prompt

```
$ ./test.exe
```

However, if you are in a directory, say `C:\Dev` in the DOS command prompt, that won't work. DOS thinks '/' means "start of a parameter":

```
C:\Dev\> dir /w
```

outputs "wide" format dir

So, if you're using DOS, you just need to type:

```
test.exe
```

or

```
.\test.exe
```

e.g.

```
C:\Dev\> test.exe
C:\Dev\> .\test.exe
C:\Dev\> c:\dev\test.exe
```

or if you're relying on "a.out"

```
C:\Dev\> a.out
C:\Dev\> .\a.out
```